# The difference about voice input and typing input in capsule

Tags: bixby

In capsule there has a function which is send message to someone,this function has two required parameters(contact and message). When user say "send message to Tom",not contains message content,bixby will hints user input message content.But there has different result when I use voice input and typing input,voice input is not be recognised,but when I use typing input the same message content,it can be recognised.So I want to know why the same one utterance causes different result by voice input and typing input?

I try to test many utterances,these utterances are not training case, but it seems that typing input can be correctly recognised,but voice input has poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding voice input vs keyboard input. As long as ASR can recognize and turn into exact words, the result should be the same. You can see the text after your voice input. If your voice input is interpreted as **sent message to tom**, the trained **send message to tom** utterance may not trigger.

Please check carefully what ASR text output is from your voice input.

You may want to provide additional content about what **many utterances** you used to test and what training utterance you already have. There is also the possibility that you just need add more training utterances.